# Mathematica. Two ArcCos functions which should give the same result are giving different results

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have written two lines of code in mathematica

```
    Integrate[ArcCos[(1-(w/2t))],{w,0,F}]]
```

and

```
    Integrate[ArcCos[-w/(2t)],{w,-2t,F-2t}]
```

where in both cases F < 2t.

I expect these two lines to give the same result but this is not the case. When I give try an equals it gives equals false.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your help

James

Comment: with `t=1,F=2` both give 2.  (after fixing unbalanced parenthesis.. )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is specifically for when t and F are undefined however. (I will fix the parenthesis)

Comment: I see -- you can demonstrate this issue more simply with `Integrate[ArcCos[-w], {w, -1, f - 1}]` and `Integrate[ArcCos[ - (w-1)], {w, 0, f}]`. this second case produces an obviously wrong complex result.  Try posting on mathematica.stackexchange.com